# JBoss virual-host and context-root

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, virtualhost

In my jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web version="8.0" xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
    <context-root>SampleSpringBoot</context-root>
    <virtual-host>SampleSpringBoot</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

standalone.xml

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
    <host name="SampleSpringBoot" alias="123.mydomain.com" default-web-module="SampleSpringBoot.war"/>
```

when i accessing "123.mydomain.com", then i can able to view the application index page.

When i accessing "http://localhost:8080/SampleSpringBoot", its not working 404 returns

I had tried with

```
<host name="SampleSpringBoot" alias="123.mydomain.com, SampleSpringBoot" default-web-module="SampleSpringBoot.war"/>
```

same 404 retuns

How can i access the url locally?

Thanks

Comment: localhost is already taken on the default-host. If you don't want to move localhost from the default-host and move it to your SampleSpringBoot host, use something like `<host name="SampleSpringBoot" alias="123.mydomain.com,something" default-web-module="SampleSpringBoot.war"/>` and then create an entry on the hosts file of your OS pointing "something" to 127.0.0.1. You should be able to access it with `http://something:8080/`

Comment: Very good information. I got it. Thanks